# postgresql listens only on localhost after reboot (restarting postgresql fixes the problem)

Tags: networking, systemd, postgresql

I'm seeing this strange behaviour where, after a reboot, PG started via `postgresql@11-main` (systemd) listens to only `127.0.0.1:5432` even through the PG conf file clearly has the following:

```
listen_addresses = '[EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS - REDACTED], 127.0.0.1'
```

Once I restart via `systemctl restart postgresql@11-main` it listens on 5432 on both the IP addresses.

PS: I have disabled the magic `postgresql.service` after reading some posts that it causes problems/confusion. However, that did not fix the problem.

#### `/lib/systemd/system/postgresl@.service`

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
AssertPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# -: ignore startup failure (recovery might take arbitrarily long)
# the actual pg_ctl timeout is configured in pg_ctl.conf
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
# 0 is the same as infinity, but "infinity" needs systemd 229
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
TimeoutStopSec=1h
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/var/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### `systemctl status`

```
# systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)


# systemctl status postgresql@11-main
● postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-02-18 09:10:43 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 1121 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast 11-main stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1128 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 11-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1134 (postgres)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@11-main.service
           ├─1134 /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
           ├─1136 postgres: 11/main: checkpointer   
           ├─1137 postgres: 11/main: background writer   
           ├─1138 postgres: 11/main: walwriter   
           ├─1139 postgres: 11/main: autovacuum launcher   
           ├─1140 postgres: 11/main: stats collector   
           ├─1141 postgres: 11/main: pglogical supervisor   
           ├─1142 postgres: 11/main: logical replication launcher   
           ├─1184 postgres: 11/main: b2b b2b [REDACTED](32854) idle
           └─1210 postgres: 11/main: b2b b2b [REDACTED](41872) idle

Feb 18 09:10:41 prod-dataserver systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
Feb 18 09:10:43 prod-dataserver systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
```

#### Ubuntu version

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

#### systemd version

```
# systemd --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue as mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/787426/postgresql-not-listening-on-local-eth1-after-reboot -- the postgres systemd config file is buggy and does not wait for the network to come-up before starting postgres.

The solution at https://serverfault.com/a/788044/117598 fixed the problem.

**Caveat:** Please edit the file in `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service`. Placing a new file to `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@.service` *should* work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that replacing explicit IP address in postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '[EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS - REDACTED], 127.0.0.1'
```

to any IP address also helps:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```